# Upload JSON file error

Tags: php

I want to ulpload JSON and txt files to the server with a size of 200KB.

This is the script I'm using:

```
$allowedExts = array("json", "txt");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/json")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/txt"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Código do erro: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "upload" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Gravado em: " . $diretorio . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file.";
}
```

But I always get the "Invalid file" error. Why is it?

Comment: Use `print_r($_FILES)` to find out.

Comment: Which tells you that no file was uploaded. I wonder why you didn't get a notice. Have you perhaps posted your question about non-working code without enabling error_reporting beforehand?!

Comment: Please post the HTML form you're using.

Comment: I'm using <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="upload"/>
With the following Jquery: $('#fileupload').change(function(){
 window.location.href = 'upload.php';
 $console.text("File uploaded");
});

Comment: @mario: I get Notice: Undefined index: file. You're right...

Comment: Are you actually POSTing JSON string data or performing a physical file upload?

Comment: @MikeBrant: a file upload

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually ever submitting your form.  Your javascript simply loads a new page in the browser window (upload.php) when you change the value of `upload` field.

Please read this article on how to upload files using jQuery, as it is not as straightforward as one would hope.

[How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Or, if your intent is to actually redirect to this a new page (rather than upload a file without reload of page in browser), then you can simply do a traditional non-AJAX form for the file upload as is outlined in the answer by @OlafErlandsen here.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is to upload the file asynchronously, I didn't expect it to be this difficult. The article will help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML form use *enctype*:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And use this content type( to avoid problems ):

```
$types = array('application/json','application/x-javascript','text/javascript','text/x-javascript','text/x-json');
if( in_array( $_FILES['file']['type'] , $types ) )
```

And, if you use jQuery:

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function ( response ){ console.log( "ok" ); },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false
});
```

And, try upload with this class:

> https://github.com/erlandsen/upload

Good Luck!